# C++ Including files error

Tags: c++, file, include

I have multiple sub folders with folders inside of them in my solution and when I'm trying to include this one file it just will not work when it is called "title_bar_widget.h". If it's called "title_bar.h" it will work just fine, but if it was any other character added to it, boom. No such file or directory error appears 'on runtime' not during editing but when you build the solution the error occurs. This is the strangest thing I've ever faced in my life. Any ideas?

Comment: What compiler? What IDE? Are you sure the file names match?

Comment: Is this a question of the total number of characters in the path of the included file? I.e. if you try to include from a shorter path (by one character), can you then use one character more in the file name?

Comment: I'm positive the file names match...

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2017

Comment: Yunnosch, I can include any character lower than "title_bar" but anything higher it will give an error, as I mentioned above. But any other name will work such as "window_widget" etc.

Comment: It also says when trying to open the file in visual studio "not found in current source file's directory, well obviously it's not it's in a different folder but that exact path is specified and it doesn't do this with any other one of my files? It makes no sense. I just tested it again and it is any file name now apparently.